# Pixel perfect и macbook

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, photoshop

коллеги, крик души.
Не так давно купил macbook pro 16, разрешение тут (3456 × 2234)
У меня есть задача, это верстка макета из photoshop.
Столкнулся вот, с чем, после того, как я вставляю через pixel perfect изображение макета на страницу, которое по ширине 1920px -- изображение отображается на половину дисплея (по сути, логично, ведь разрешение моего дисплея больше 3к по ширине). Вот скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А браузер (хром) видимо ввиду большого разрешения дисплея искусственно увеличивает весь контент в браузере, судя по dev tools ширина страницы 1728px, так же прикладываю скрин.
[image: http://joxi.ru/zAND9oKIvQyeRm]

В общем вопрос вот в чем? А как верстать по пиксель перфекту на мак, если при фактическом отображении контента операционная система искусственно увеличивает контент, а в случае вставки изображения макета на страницу через пиксель перфект он вставляется без увеличения? Очень жду любых советов, большое спасибо!

Comment: Потому что не надо верстать по pixel perfect, это извращение)

Comment: А так вообще, скорее всего где-то есть какая-то настройка для отключения retina. Ну или обратно скэйлить браузер

Comment: Хорошо, но даже если и так, если отказаться от Pixel perfect, то каким образом можно проверить совпадение верстки к макету? Только на глаз?

Comment: Никакое не извращение сверять верстку по pp, если макет нарисован с соблюдением сетки и отступов то и pp все будет хорошо. А что за проблема у вас я не поняла, Посмотрите масштабирование браузера, часто из за него pp ложится на сайт неправильно. Используйте разрешение, которое указано в макете. иногда неправильно нарисованный макет в фотошопе при формировании/конвертировании png может неправильно лечь на сайт. С фигмой такого не замечала.

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui Ну вот если по сетке, и если нормальный верстальщик с опытом – никакие пиксельперфекты не нужны. Всё равно идеально не сверстаешь ничего, есть масса устройств и разрешений, и сидеть пиксели ковырять – никакого времени не хватит, скорее бизнес развалится.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а и не надо ковырять рр на каждом устройстве и разрешении. Дизайнер предоставил 3и разрешения, сверяешь рр на этих разрешениях и смотришь что бы на устройстве все было ок, это может быть либо резиновая верстка, либо центрирование по контейнеру. Я работаю уже больше 3х лет в компании и там применяют рр. Ничего, довольно много лет работают по этой технике, не разорились)

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui, ну, судя по всему, у вас там слишком простой дизайн, или куча косяков в промежуточных версиях...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вы не правы

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui Я это вижу именно так, и работаю с версткой, включая большие проекты. Я не собираюсь спорить о том, кто прав или нет, мне всё равно. Если считаете, что я не прав – хорошо, оставайтесь при своём мнении.

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui проблема вот в чем, попытаюсь объяснить по другому. У меня дисплей Retina и фактическое его разрешение - 3456 × 2234. Но система, видимо ввиду того, что на таком дисплее отобразить контент в таком разрешении невозможно ввиду размера монитора - то он увеличивает контент вдвое, я на одном из скринов указал, что Dev Tools показывает ширину страницы - 1728px, то есть вдвое меньше. А когда я пытаюсь наложить изображение макета (его ширина 1920)  на страницу - изображение отображается на примерно 3/4 по ширине (видно на скрине), как будто ширина страницы 3456px...

Comment: Я уверен, что есть какое-то решение, просто я о нем не знаю... Ошибся, не на 3/4, а чуть больше 1/2